# How can i use HTextView scale textview effect (com.hanks.htextview.HTextView) as multiline effect?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-animation, textview

At the moment it works with single line and when I input a text with more than one line, the application crashes.

MainActivity:

```
    HTextView tvQuestion_hanks = (HTextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQs_hanks);
    tvQuestion_hanks.setAnimateType(HTextViewType.SCALE);
    tvQuestion_hanks.animateText("Hello world");
```

Layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:htext="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


         <com.hanks.htextview.HTextView

                android:id="@+id/tvQs_hanks"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:text="Question"
                htext:animateType="scale"
                android:gravity="start">

         </com.hanks.htextview.HTextView>

     </RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried different layout codes like;

```
     android:lines="5"
     android:maxLines="5"
     android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

but it didn't work . This is my logcat just after i press the button and a multiline text is sent to HTextView (as I said the app crashes) :

```
            02-13 20:01:18.074 4456-4456/com.example.moham.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: 
            Shutting down VM
            02-13 20:01:18.074 4456-4456/com.example.moham.myapplication W/dalvikvm: 
            threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x94caeb20)
            02-13 20:01:18.074 4456-4456/com.example.moham.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: 
            FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.moham.myapplication, PID: 
           4456
                                                                           java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
           length=100; index=100
                                                                               at 
           com.hanks.htextview.animatetext.HText.prepareAnimate(HText.java:88)
                                                                               at 
           com.hanks.htextview.animatetext.HText.animateText(HText.java:74)
                                                                               at 
           com.hanks.htextview.HTextView.animateText(HTextView.java:107)
                                                                               at 
           com.example.moham.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
                                                                               at 
           android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                               at 
           android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                               at 
           android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                               at 
           android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                               at 
           android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native 
           Method)
                                                                               at 
           java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                               at 
           com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                               at 
           com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native 
           Method)
```

HTextView GitHub page: https://github.com/hanks-zyh/HTextView

HTextView GitHub page2: https://github.com/yikwing/HTextView

Comment: can you post your logcat to see what is the problem?

Comment: plus, from the HTextView github link you provided, seems like it does support multi-line texts (look at the "fade" example). Maybe you can go to the github's page and use their exact layout-source-code

Comment: I've tried some of "fade" example codes on my project , but it didn't work :(    . The  "scale" effect is also crashes for multiline text entry.

Comment: @Re'em , I've added the logcat , help me solve it please .

Comment: as you can see, the exception being thrown is inside the class
com.hanks.htextview.animatetext.HText
I would suspect a bug in this library. Send them a link to this stackoverflow question and ask them for support in this bug. I can't do more than that to help with a 3rd library. Good luck!

Comment: @Re'em , okay . Thanks for your comment :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this problem , not just by means of it's right way , but it finally worked . As "Re'em" noticed in the comments , this is a bug from the HTextView main library so i asked it's developers to solve it , but i was in a big hurry , so i solved it this way :

As the HTextView is only able to handle a one-line text entry , I wrote a Function in order to measure the approximate possible amount of chars along the screen-width by :

First ) Finding text width in pixels.

Second ) Dividing it into text length.

```
    PixelPerChar = TXT_width / TXT.length();
```

And then , in order to approximate possible amount of chars along the screen-width , i divided screen-width into PixelPerChar , so the result is an approximate number of chars that fit correctly along the screen and it won't exceed a one-line text .

```
    PossibleChars = lcdWidth() / PixelPerChar;
```

The next step is to adding HtextViews to a LinearLayout one after another , Substring the text into one-line serries at the same time , and send it to each HTextView created , until the text becomes shorter than the screen-width .

Take a look at the full function code : (Qs = Question = text   :)

```
private void QsPrint(String Qs){

    LinearLayout LinearLay1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLay1);
    LinearLay1.removeAllViews();


    int Qswidth = QsWidth(tvQuestion_hanks , Qs);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = MainMenu.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int lcdwidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    int lcdheight = metrics.heightPixels;



    int PIXperCHAR = Qswidth / Qs.length();
    SubStart = 0;
    SubEnd = lcdwidth / PIXperCHAR;
    sub1 = "";


    while (true)
    {


        HTextView tvQs_Hanks_multiline = new HTextView(MainMenu.this);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout
                .LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        tvQs_Hanks_multiline.setLayoutParams(params1);
        tvQs_Hanks_multiline.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, PixelToDp((int)(tvQuestion_hanks.getTextSize())));
        tvQs_Hanks_multiline.setAnimateType(HTextViewType.SCALE);
        LinearLay1.addView(tvQs_Hanks_multiline);

        sub1 = "";
        if(Qswidth >= lcdwidth) {
                try {
                    sub1 = Qs.substring(SubStart, SubEnd);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    QsPrintSubString(Qs);
                }


            while (QsWidth(tvQs_Hanks_multiline , sub1) >= lcdwidth){
                SubEnd --;
                sub1 = Qs.substring(SubStart, SubEnd);
            }

            SubEnd -=4; // For spacing before/after the TXT
            sub1 = Qs.substring(SubStart, SubEnd);
            tvQs_Hanks_multiline.animateText("   "+sub1+"");
        }
        else if(Qswidth < lcdwidth){
            sub1 = Qs;
            tvQs_Hanks_multiline.animateText("   " + sub1 + "");
            break;
        }




        if(Qswidth >= lcdwidth) {

            Qs = Qs.substring(SubEnd, Qs.length());
            Qswidth = QsWidth(tvQs_Hanks_multiline , Qs);
            PIXperCHAR = Qswidth / Qs.length();
            SubStart = 0;
            if(Qswidth >= lcdwidth) {
                SubEnd = lcdwidth / PIXperCHAR;
            }
        }



    }

}
```

I used this function to calculate the text width in pixels :

```
private int QsWidth(TextView tv , String Question){

    String Qs = Question;
    Rect bound = new Rect();
    Paint textPaint = tv.getPaint();
    textPaint.getTextBounds(Qs, 0, Qs.length(), bound);
    int QsWidth = bound.width();

    return QsWidth;
}
```

Pixel to dp convertor function :

```
public static int PixelToDp(int px)
{
    return (int) (px / Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

And finally , i used this function because some times the text length is a special amount of chars that the "QsPrint" function can not Substring it correctly and crashes :( , so i used this function .

It works so simple , it continuously reduces the SubEnd and tests the Substring again.

the function will keep running until it doesn't crash any more :)

```
private void QsPrintSubString(String Qs){

    SubEnd--;
    try {
        sub1 = Qs.substring(SubStart, SubEnd);
    }catch (Exception e){
        QsPrintSubString(Qs);
    }
}
```

XML layout:

( tvQs_hanks you see below is almost useless , it's just needed in "QsWidth()" function in order to calculate the text width before we create any HTextView in our LinearLayout  )

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:htext="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">




            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLay1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">


            </LinearLayout>

            <com.hanks.htextview.HTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvQs_hanks"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Question"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                htext:animateType="scale">

            </com.hanks.htextview.HTextView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method... It will surely work for you as it's working perfectly for me with ***multiline text*** as well...

**Thanks me later :)**

Animations are a great way to bring life into our app. Animating views are easy, but How to animate text. For animating text (not TextView) we are going to use HTextView a free library available on GitHub.

For this demo app, we have six HTextView and we are animating different texts in all the HTextView. For using HTextView we are going to add HTextView dependencies in-app Gradle file.

**build.gradle (Module:App)**

```
def htextview_version = "0.1.2"
compile "com.hanks:htextview-base:$htextview_version"        // base library
compile "com.hanks:htextview-fall:$htextview_version"        // optional
compile "com.hanks:htextview-fade:$htextview_version"        // optional
compile "com.hanks:htextview-line:$htextview_version"        // optional
compile "com.hanks:htextview-rainbow:$htextview_version"     // optional
compile "com.hanks:htextview-typer:$htextview_version"       // optional
compile "com.hanks:htextview-scale:$htextview_version"       // optional
compile "com.hanks:htextview-evaporate:$htextview_version"   // optional
```

Sync, your project.

Following are the code for **activity_main.xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.hanks.htextview.fall.FallTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
         />


    <com.hanks.htextview.line.LineTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/textViewLine"
        app:animationDuration="1000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:lineColor="#1367bc"
        app:lineWidth="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <com.hanks.htextview.fade.FadeTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/textViewFade"
        app:animationDuration="1000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />


    <com.hanks.htextview.typer.TyperTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/textViewTyper"
        app:charIncrease="3"
        app:typerSpeed="80"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />


    <com.hanks.htextview.rainbow.RainbowTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/textViewRainBow"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:colorSpace="150dp"
        app:colorSpeed="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />


    <com.hanks.htextview.scale.ScaleTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/textViewScale"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

In our **MainActivity.java** file, we are first initializing all the HTextView. We have a String Array for different messages. We are changing all HTextView text with time using String Array. Following is the code for **MainActivity.java** file...

```
package com.vlemonn.java.blog.htextview;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.hanks.htextview.base.HTextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    private HTextView textView,textViewScale,textViewRainBow,textViewTyper,textViewFade,textViewLine;
    int delay = 2000; //milliseconds
    Handler handler;
    ArrayList<String> arrMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    int position=0;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /* Some Sample Messages for Animation */
        arrMessages.add("Hello, vLemonn!");
        arrMessages.add("Hello, World!");
        arrMessages.add("Free Android Tutorials");
        arrMessages.add("By Mayank Sanghvi");
        arrMessages.add("@vLemonn");
        arrMessages.add("Subscribe, Share, Like");
        arrMessages.add("Support Us");
        
        /* Initialize HTextView */
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textViewScale= findViewById(R.id.textViewScale);
        textViewRainBow= findViewById(R.id.textViewRainBow);
        textViewTyper= findViewById(R.id.textViewTyper);
        textViewFade= findViewById(R.id.textViewFade);
        textViewLine= findViewById(R.id.textViewLine);

        /* First Message */
        textView.animateText(arrMessages.get(position));
        textViewScale.animateText(arrMessages.get(position));
        textViewRainBow.animateText(arrMessages.get(position));
        textViewTyper.animateText(arrMessages.get(position));
        textViewFade.animateText(arrMessages.get(position));
        textViewLine.animateText(arrMessages.get(position));
        position++;
        
        /* Change Messages every 2 Seconds */
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){

                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
                if(position>=arrMessages.size())
                    position=0;
                textView.animateText(arrMessages.get(position));
                textViewScale.animateText(arrMessages.get(position));
                textViewRainBow.animateText(arrMessages.get(position));
                textViewTyper.animateText(arrMessages.get(position));
                textViewFade.animateText(arrMessages.get(position));
                textViewLine.animateText(arrMessages.get(position));
                position++;
            }
        }, delay);

    }
}
```

**Final Demo (Output):**
[Final Demo (Output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfJUM.gif)

**If you find this answer useful then please Accept it so that everyone can use this easily...**

Comment: @Elikill58 I have updated answer with detailed explanation... Now you can refer the answer. Thank you for your feedback... Cheers :)